# Left Align an ordered list's numbers

Tags: html, css

How can I left align the numbers of an ordered listed so instead of being aligned at the . like image below, they are aligned at the number.

[image]

```html
<ol>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
<li>g</li>
<li>h</li>
<li>i</li>
<li>j</li>
<li>k</li>
<li>l</li>
</ol>
```

I want the numbers aligned the other way so that 9 is aligned with the 1 in 10.

Comment: Can you link some code?

Comment: Code added. Run it, and it will look just like the picture. I want the numbers aligned the other way so that 9 is aligned with the 1 in 10.

Comment: and what have you tried? the code is a simple ol list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a weird thing to do. But here is how you can accomplish it.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li{
  position: relative;
}
li p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
<li><p>1</p></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you!